# jQuery attr is removing classes

Tags: jquery

I have several elements with classes on and I am  trying to increase the number on each li by 1

But using the method below removes the classes already applied to the divs, is there a different way this can be done?

http://jsfiddle.net/87x7huqk/1/

```
$('.list > li').each(function (index) {
    $(this).attr('class', (index + 1));
});
```

Comment: what do you mean *the number on each*? What would the final result be ?

Comment: If you look at the fiddle each li is counting upwards - 1,2,3 etc. Its just removing the other classes on the li which I need to keep

Comment: Because you're not `addClass`ing, you're setting the attr "class".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to add an extra class that contains the index then use the `.addClass()` method

```
$('.list > li').each(function (index) {
    $(this).addClass((index + 1).toString());
});
```

Updated demo at http://jsfiddle.net/87x7huqk/2/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `addClass()`, not the `attr()` method:

```
$('.list > li').each(function (index) {
    $(this).addClass((index + 1).toString());
});
```

`addClass()` as the name suggests, *adds* a class to the element's classList; whereas using `attr()` to set the `'class'` attribute sets the class attribute to the passed-in string.  However you could use the anonymous function available to `attr()`:

```
$('.list > li').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('class', function (index, currentClasses) {
        return currentClasses + ' ' + (index + 1);
    });
});
```

However a class-name really shouldn't, due to awkwardness in selecting the elements in CSS, start with a numeral (though it is valid, under HTML 5).

Comment: In your first snippet you need to convert to string because the `.addClass` methods breaks out early if the parameter is not a function or a string. (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes/classes.js#L13-L23)

Comment: I had wondered why your answer incorporated the `toString()` call. That'd be why, then, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem one, you're overwriting the entire `class` attribute. To add a class without effecting others, you use jQuery's `addClass`.

```
$('.list > li').each(function (index) {
    $(this).addClass(index + 1));
});
```

Problem two, you're trying to add a number as a class--unless your doctype is for HTML5, a class cannot start with a number.